# It should be possible to log in in the middle of writing a question, without losing it

Tags: feature-request

I wrote a question on meta.stackoverflow.com without realizing that I was not logged-in. If I had logged in from the same tab, I would have lost my work. I worked around this by logging in in a new tab, then copy-pasting my work over, but this is not idea.

It should be possible to log in without losing your work.

Comment: I just save my work in a text editor. Anyway, I haven't found this to be a really big problem.

Comment: I don't think that it is a big problem either, but it is a problem. Ignoring little problems tends to add up after a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can log in (and post in the same action) using the "OpenID Login" input below the question:

[image]

(For Meta there's just one option: OpenID. For those using Google, see "[I am [..]@gmail.com, what is my open id?](https://superuser.com/questions/38186/i-am-johngmail-com-what-is-my-open-id)" at Super User.)

Comment: yes, you can log in and post in the same action

Comment: That only works if you know your OpenID login. If you're like most people, and just click the "google" icon (or whatever your provider is) to log in, this isn't an option.

Comment: @Matthew, I think most people do know their OpenID login, but indeed Google is different. (It's about time Google implements a regular OpenID.) See "I am [..]@gmail.com, what is my open id?" at http://superuser.com/questions/38186/i-am-johngmail-com-what-is-my-open-id

Answer (score 3):

To me, it's a nice-to-have feature, not critical. I'll certainly welcome it though I probably will never use it. I guess most active users are 'always' logged in anyway.