# Writing a long post... losing everything

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor, draft

So I recently signed up for Stack Overflow and wanted to write my first question.

Then, after carefully wording it and writing the post (it took.. I don't know, 20 minutes), I click on "log in" (as in: before posting it said: either login or fill out this form, and since I already have an account I click "login". However, I assume it asked me for the login because I switched to the http://security.stackexchange.com section instead of Stack Overflow when I registered, maybe you should combine the login for all?). Then it successfully logs in, however my post I just wrote is lost.

How frustrating.

Clicking on the back button doesn't bring my long post into existence either. It has vanished.

Comment: The site automatically saves drafts and should prevent this from happening. Maybe you lose the draft when you log in...

Comment: Weird. Wasn't there another post complaining about the same thing earlier today?

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm [Kind of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119082/how-to-make-stack-overflow-not-lose-answers), but his problem was an error dialog he didn't notice. I don't know why anyone would expect a site to keep form data when they navigate away from the page; sites generally don't work that way (even though SO does have drafts)

Comment: @Michael thanks for the link. The OP's situation is different from what you say about navigating away, though: He wrote something into the form provided, and was told to log in in the next step. I find it fair to expect that that won't destroy the content entered. If SO really presents him with an empty form after logging in, that is pretty bad. (I don't think it's normally that way though)

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm Oh, I see; putting the link after the question fields does imply that you won't lose data. I just tested it and it saved my draft when I logged in; not sure what went wrong here

Comment: Which is why the rest of my compose our posts in `emacs` ;)

Comment: @Marvin I did use [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) back when I used Firefox, and it was fantastic. I wish I could find an equivalent for Chrome

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Nothing similar to It's All Text, but I find [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno) indispensable

Comment: Might this be related to [the one-time global login reset](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118478/global-login-reset-in-the-near-future) that happened last week? If I understand correctly, one cannot even start typing a question when not logged in on Stack Overflow? For other sites, logging in *while* writing a question is possible, but that should show the login [right below the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34110/it-should-be-possible-to-log-in-in-the-middle-of-writing-a-question-without-los/34116#34116). So, the login flow you saw seems odd to me. (cc: @Pekka)

Comment: (@Peter, where does it say the names should use non-breaking spaces?)

Comment: (@Arjan: it doesn't say. It is just a little bit less confusing to read if the two words are on the same line (at the expense of short lines in some cases), especially as they are both common words.)

Comment: (Ah, @Peter, then I feel you're mixing content with presentation. Please consider how it looks while editing, especially on devices that have no preview, and how it might affect other things we're not thinking of. Like maybe even Data Explorer queries, but I know that is an extreme example.)

Answer (score 0):

It has been well over 2 years, closing this as a no-repro. If the issue remains please open a new bug.